# question about using mpl::range_c with mpl::fold

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl, boost-mp11

i have below simple function to convert a mpl::vector<...> to pack<...>

```
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template <typename... Ts>
struct pack{};
struct A{};
struct B{};

template <typename... P>
struct mp_append_impl;

template <template <typename...> typename P, typename... Ts, typename T>
struct mp_append_impl<P<Ts...>, T>
{
    using type = P<Ts..., T>;
};

template <template <typename...> typename P, typename T>
struct mp_append_impl<P<void>, T>
{
    using type = P<T>;
};

template <typename S>
struct mpl_to_pack
{
    using SEQ = mpl::range_c<int, 0, mpl::size<S>::type::value>;
    using type =
        typename mpl::fold<SEQ, pack<void>, mp_append_impl<mpl::_1, typename mpl::at<S, mpl::_2>::type>>::type;
};

void main() {

    std::cout << std::endl
              << boost::typeindex::type_id<mpl_to_pack<mpl::vector<A, B>>::type>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
}
```

why this function output pack<mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_> instead of pack<A, B>?